# A set consisting of a single vector v is linearly dependent if and only if v = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

Wouldn't any set consisting of any single vector v be linearly dependent because it can be expressed as a linear combination c**v** where c = 1? 1 times any vector is itself, right? I don't understand why that would only be true if **v = 0.**

Comment: If $v\ne 0$, then $av=0$ implies $a=0$ , so the set {$v$} is, per definition, linear independent.

Comment: The argument you mean is : Two vectors $u,v\ne 0$ are linear dependent, if and only if there is a real number $a$ with $au=v$. This only applies , if you have two vectors.

Comment: I thought that the definition of linear dependence was that a vector in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of other vectors in the set? So I thought if a vector in a set could be expressed as a linear combination of itself then it would be linearly dependent.

Comment: Ah okay, just saw your second comment.

Comment: The actual definition is : A set {$v_1,\cdots v_n$} is linear independent if and only if $a_1v_1+\cdots +a_nv_n=0$ implies $a_1=\cdots =a_n$.

Comment: If all vectors are nonzero, then in fact there is at least one vector being a linear combination of all the others, if the vectors are linear dependent.

Comment: Okay thanks, make perfect sense now.

Answer (score 2):

A set (better, a list) $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ of vectors is linearly dependent if there exist $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ not all zero with $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n=0$

If $n=1$, you have your statement:

- if $v_1=0$, then $a_1=1$ can be chosen so $a_1v_1=0$, making the list consisting of the zero vector linearly dependent;
- if $v_1\ne0$, then $a_1v_1=0$ implies $a_1=0$; thus the list consisting of $v_1\ne0$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of linear independence of a set of vectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is that if $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$, then $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$. When there’s only one vector in the set, this is obviously true: the only way to get the zero vector is to multiply this lone vector by zero.

This definition is indeed equivalent to saying that the set is linearly dependent if some vector in the set can be written as a linear combination of the *other* vectors. When there’s only one vector, though, there are no other vectors left over to form this linear combination, so a set consisting of a single vector can’t be linearly dependent.